# C++: Should I use constants as much as possible in function arguments?

Tags: c++, standards, constants

Or is it pointless?

Thanks.

Edit: I have seen char arrays often constant in function arguments... is there a reason for that?

Edit 2: Nevermind my edit. See 'In silico's answer.

Edit 3: TO CLARIFY, this is an etiquette question, not a "what is going to happen" question. I understand what `const` does.

Comment: use the arguments you need :)

Comment: Use the widgets that make the gizmos perform the tasklets that will produce the result you need.

Comment: Do you mean the use of `const` in function declarations?

Comment: Do not confuse the `const` modifier with a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `const` whenever you are dealing with references (&) and do not intend to change the argument. This is, to clearly identify them as input arguments. Performance should be better, too. And thousands of other reasons. It is probably useless on arguments handed over by value, but doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this function declaration:

```
void Foo(const char* str);
```

This declares a function called `foo` that accepts a pointer to a `const char`. The `const` in this context means that the function promises to not change the contents of the stuff pointed by `str`.

It has to do with [const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness) and is a fundamental part of the language. The fact that you had to ask for something relatively simple means that you should go [pick up a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read through it. You'll gain a much better understanding of how to use it and why we even bother with it.

Also, read up on const-correctness [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) and [here](http://gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm). Again, it's a fundamental part of the language and it's important that you get it right if you want to code in proper C++.

Answer (score 0):

`const` is a promise that you won't change the thing in question. You can make promises not to change a parameter, not to change the thing that a pointer points at (or a reference refers to), not to change the `this` -object (in a member function), etc. For a return value, the "promise" is binding upon the caller, so it's actually more like you're disallowing the caller to change the returned thing.

This is more useful with pointers and references (especially references, since in C++ we prefer not to pass by pointer if we don't have to) than with values, since passing by value makes a copy anyway; the caller doesn't care if the called function changes its own copy of a value. But if we pass by reference, `const` lets us know that the function won't change our value via the reference.

Similarly, when we return something by reference, we're generally referring to a pre-existing thing - perhaps most commonly, we return some data member by reference from a member function. In this case, `const` prevents the caller from using this reference to modify the object. That, again, makes it easier to reason about what the code does, and protects against mistakes. It's common to see accessor functions in pairs: one non-const version, and one const version where both the return value and the this-object are const. (We make the this-object const by putting `const` at the **end** of the function signature, **after** the closing parenthesis of the parameter list.) The meaning: "calling this function will not affect the object, as long as the caller doesn't mutate the object via the returned reference". If the caller has a const instance of the class, then only a const reference can be returned.

For more, please read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html .

Comment: Thanks, but I know what "const" does for the most part. My question was more of a code etiquette thing.